# Neural Network gives exact same values of previous day for 1 day ahead prediction

Tags: regression, time-series, neural-networks

I have hourly data for 365 days, and I would like to train a neural network model for 7 days and predict 8th day hourly data. It is a time series 24-h ahead regression problem. I am also applying such an approach instead of predicting all day data I am predicting each hour, so my neural network model has 1 output and 6 inputs. We can think that each days and each hours are features.
I am training the model as follows
Xtrain = Day-1 Hour-1, Day-2 Hour-1 ... Day-6 Hour-1 (6 sample,1 feature), Ytrain = Day-7 Hour-1, after training I am giving Day-7 Hour-1 to predict Day-8 Hour-1

Xtrain = Day-2 Hour-1, Day-3 Hour-1 ... Day-7 Hour-1 (6 sample, 1 feature), Ytrain = Day-8 Hour-1, after training I am giving Day-8 Hour-1 to predict Day-9 Hour-1

After I predict all hour-1 values I am repeating this for Hour-2, Hour-3 ... Hour-24.
This procedure goes up to 365 days.
First of all, Is this approach valid?

The problem is, the model predicts the exact same values of previous day. 
[image: Exact same values of previous day!]

Why do you think this happens, what might be the issue?

I have also tried training with l2 regularizer, but results are almost same.

NN --> 6 Inputs -> 12 Hidden Neuron -> 1 Output.
Using Adam optimizer, 5k Epochs and RandomUniform Initializer.

EDIT: Same happened if I use choose 8 random hourly value as feature for each day as
Xtrain = D1-h6 D1-h8 D1-h10 D1-h12 D1-h14 D1-h16 D1-h18 D1-h20 ... D2 ..... D6
Ytrain = D7 h1 to h24
Xtest = D2-h6 D2-h8 D2-h10 D2-h12 D2-h14 D2-h16 D2-h18 D2-h20 ... D3 ..... D7
Predict = D8 h1 to h24

D8 values are exactly the same with D7 values.

Comment: Are the two smaller values because of Saturday and Sunday?

Comment: Maybe the learning rate is too high. It could "overwrite" what it learned previously and that's why it only predicts the same as last day. Try setting to to a low value, such as 0.05 or 0.1. Are you using a Recurrent Neural net, such as LSTM?

Comment: thanks for the comments. I am using Multi Layer Perceptron. Learning rate is 0.001. To be more specific keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)

Comment: this is solar irradiance data, days have no affect on it, so I didn't include days to the model.

Comment: Try taking the first-differences of your time series and using the first-differences as your target.